# колорама не работает

Tags: python, windows, colorama

я хочу написать код но колорама не работает посмотрите может колорама не работает с imput()

```
from colorama import init, Fore
init(autoreset=True)
while True:
    input(Fore.YELLOW + "вы :")
```

после написанного выходит

←[33mвы :

это выводит в консоли приложения не в IDLE Shel
как это исправить и заранее спасибо

Comment: у вас while написан с большой буквы.

Comment: Что такое "выводит в самой программе"?

Comment: Ну если выводит - значит работает. А это уже проблема шелла, что он не понимает что такое [33m

Comment: Не на тот вопрос дубликатом закрыл изначально, поменял